# Colorize a photo with PHP/GD

Tags: php, colors, overlay

Let's say I have some original jpg image and I want to add red with 50% opacity over the image and display it on the page, how it's done with GD? Please just point me in the right direction, my googling and searching didn't give me much results, or maybe I don't know what I'm searching for because english isn't my 1st language.

Example from photoshop:
[image]

Comment: yesss, thanks, that's what i'm searching for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could either [draw a rectangle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledrectangle.php) and

```
$red = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 255, 0, 0, 63);
```

Or you could use the PHP Image [filters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php),

```
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 127, 0, 0);
```

// didn't test the color though

Comment: `50` should be `127 / 2 = 63`?

Comment: excellent, php is amazing